# Можно ли в структуру вставить ф-цию?

Tags: c

Например:

```
struct st {
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int summa (int i, int j) {
        return n + m;
    }
}
```

код, конечно не работает, но можно ли сделать что-то подобное в Си?

Comment: Для этого дядюшка Бьярне придумал C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В таком виде — нет, это вам не C++. Но ничто не мешает передавать `this` явно.

К слову, пространств имён тут тоже нет, так что функцию придётся вытащить за пределы структуры.

И вообще, Си — это язык низкого уровня, без прикрас и синтаксического сахара. Так что извольте раскладывать всю программу по полочкам.

```
struct st {
    int n;
    int m;
};

void st_constructor(struct st* this)
{
    this->n = 0;
    this->m = 0;
}

int st_summa(const struct st* this) {
    return this->n + this->m;
}
```

Comment: да, я так и делаю - просто стало интересно

Answer (score 4):

Нет, в си у структур не может быть функций-членов.

Конечно, там могут быть указатели на функции, но это совсем не то, поскольку занимает место в каждом экземпляре структуры и при вызове не получает неявный this.